# Clicking on a Link in Outlook 2013 using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I wanted to click on a Link in my email body using VBScript? is this possible...
the email is in my Drafts folder. So far i have been able to navigate to my drafts folder.

```
olFolderDrafts = 16
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
Set objDrafts = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
MsgBox objDrafts.Items.Count
```

Comment: Where do you run the code? Is it an external application?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for each` loop to enumerate the items of your objDrafts, store the `HTMLBody` from the item to a variable and extract the link with a regular expression from that varable.
Clicking on it won't work since it's no GUI but you can open the link with something like this `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("http://www.google.com")`

Comment: is he has to iterate the all why shouldn't it ?

Comment: It will take a lot of time freezing the UI. Better to use Find/FindNext or Restrict methods to find the subset.